# Move query parameter value to header before auth request in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I have a location that uses [ngx_http_auth_request_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html). The authorization sub-request looks for a token in an `Authorization` header on the original request. For this particular location, the token can only be passed as a query parameter on the request (e.g. `/sites/<site-id>/charts/<chart-name>?token=<token>`).

Is it possible to set an `Authorization` header to `Bearer: <token>` (`<token>` being the value passed to the request as the `token` query parameter) *before* the auth sub-request is fired?

The location:

```
location ~* "^\/sites\/([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-?([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-?){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})\/charts\/([^\/]*\/?)$" {
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    auth_request /verify/token;
    proxy_pass http://sites:3000/$1/charts/$3;
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?  I'm in a similar boat...